# Change cursor permanently

Tags: c++, api, winapi

I'm trying to change the cursor permanently to some other cursor.

When I do this all I get is the new cursor until I move the cursor again.

```
  case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
      cursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_CROSS) ;
      SetCursor(cursor);
      break;
```

How do I change it so that it will be permanent.. I know it has something to do with wndclass..

When I make the window in wndproc I said wndclass.hIcon to IDC_ARROW but I can't call wndclass in WM_RBUTTONDOWN..

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each mouse movement causes a [`WM_SETCURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to be sent to your window; the default window procedure will respond with the configured cursor. Override to return your new cursor instead.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looked for! =).

Comment: I actually believe that Drew Dormann is more correct in this case. Whilst both solutions do work, I do believe setting your cursor ONCE (or at least "when you do certain operations") is the right thing to do, not every mouse-movement (on the graphics cards I worked with, setting the cursor was not a trivial operation - although it would "no-op" if you tried to set the same as before, it's still hundreds if not thousands of clockcycles just to get down to the driver and back out again).

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I don't think his answer works because the cursor will reset itself once you leave the current window and won't restore when you move it back. You really are expected to respond to WM_SETCURSOR each time you get it.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you need "BOTH" answers. I wrote testcode  to test cursors (and the driver code to actually manipulate the cursor), but it was about 10 years back. But  I don't remember having to  set "what shape the cursor is" every time it was moved - in fact, I'm pretty certain it was just a "Make my cursor this shape" once, and then I'd move it around checking that everything worked as it should, then select another one [I had some weird cursors too - like a 500 pixel circle with alpha blending].

Comment: @MatsPetersson Perhaps you were lucky, but setting the cursor via `WM_SETCURSOR` is the right thing to do. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/25/421707.aspx If you think it's inefficient, then sorry, but it's the way Windows works.  Even if you don't handle `WM_SETCURSOR`, Windows will still generate all of the `WM_SETCURSOR` messages, and the default window proc will then set it to the window's class cursor. (That said, I would expect an attempt to set the cursor to the current cursor to be inexpensive, so it's probably not as bad as you think anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation for `SetCursor`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If your application must set the cursor while it is in a window, make sure the class cursor for the specified window's class is set to NULL. **If the class cursor is not NULL, the system restores the class cursor each time the mouse is moved.**

You need to remove any specified cursor from your window class.